# Is GAS/google sheet an alternative option to PHP/mySQL?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep finding forum results that refer to the google visualiser for displaying my query results. But it just seems to dump the data in a pre-made table. I haven't found a way to write my own custom table dynamically.

In the past, when I have hacked together PHP to make use of mySQL DB, I would simply connect to my DB, run a query into an array, then cycle through the array and write the table in HTML. I could do IF statements in the middle for formatting or extra tweaks to the displayed data, etc. But I am struggling to find documentation on how to do something similar in a google script. What is the equivalent work flow? Can someone point me to a tutorial that will start me down this path?

I just want a simple HTML page with text box and submit button that runs a query on my Google sheet (back in the .gs file) and displays the results in a table back on the HTML page.

Maybe my understanding that GAS/google sheets is an alternative to PHP/mySQL is where I'm going wrong? Am I trying to make a smoothie with a toaster instead of a blender?

Any help appreciated

Comment: This looks like a primarily opinion-based / too broad question. What did you try? Had you already review the Google Apps Script guides?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome David. Ruben is right, it's cool to post up some code you have tried. But I spent many months getting my head around Apps-script and love to share what I know. There are several ways to get the data out of a Google sheet. There is a very well document [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) For GAS. There is also a [client API.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js).

There is the approach you mention. I suggest converting the incoming data to JSON so you can do with it as you like.

**Unauthenticated frontend queries** are also possible. Which needs the spreadsheet to be published and set to anyone with the link can view, and uses the [Google visualisation API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference)

```
var sql = 'SELECT  A,B,C,D,E,F,G where A = true order by A DESC LIMIT 10 offset '
var queryString = encodeURIComponent(sql);
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ spreadsheetId +'/gviz/tq?tq=' + queryString);
query.send(handleSampleDataQueryResponse);


   function handleSampleDataQueryResponseTotal(responsetotal) {
      var myData = responsetotal.getDataTable();
      var myObject = JSON.parse(myData.toJSON());
      console.log(myObject)
   }
```

### **Other Approaches**

**In your GAS back end** this can get all of your data in columns A to C as an array of arrays ([[row1],[row2],[row3]]).

```
 function getData(query){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var range = sheet.getRange('A1:C');
   var data = range.getValues();
   // return data after some query
 }
```

**In your GAS front end** this can [call to your backend](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

```
   var data = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).getData(query);

   var success = (e) => {
     console.log(e)
   }
```

**In your GAS backend** this can add data to your sheet. The client [side API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) will also add data, but is more complex and needs authentication.

```
 function getData(data){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   var range = sheet.getRange('A1:C');
   var data = range.setValues([[row1],[row2],[row3]]);
   return 'success!'
 }
```

**In your GAS frontend** this can send data to your backend.

```
   var updateData = [[row1],[row2],[row3]]
   var data = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).getData(updateData);

   var success = (e) => {
     console.log(e)
   }
```

### **Finally**

**Or you can get everything from the sheet as JSON and do the query in the client.** This works okay if you manipulate the data in the sheet as you will need it. This also needs the spreadsheet to be published and set to anyone with the link can view.

```
var firstSheet = function(){
  var spreadsheetID = "SOME_ID";
  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID +"/1/public/values?alt=json";
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    $.getJSON(url, (data)=>{
        let result = data.feed.entry
        resolve(result)
   });
  })
}

firstSheet().then(function(data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much - This is great - This will keep me busy for a while. You are credit to the community :)